# How to create new tab in product create page for magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-layout-xml

I have created a new tab in magento product edit page, It is working fine for me. But I could not able to show the same tab in new product create page. Here I am sharing my code for adding the product tab in admin product edit page using my custom module.

app/etc/modules/Mymodule_Customerextras.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Customerextras>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mymodule_Customerextras>
    </modules>
</config>
```

In module config.xml I have added the following

```
</config>
.......
<adminhtml>
  <layout>
    <updates>
      <customerextras>
        <file>customerextras.xml</file>
      </customerextras>
    </updates>
  </layout>
  <events>
    <catalog_product_save_after>
      <observers>
        <customerextras_save_product_data>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>customerextras/observer</class>
          <method>saveProductTabData</method>
        </customerextras_save_product_data>
      </observers>
    </catalog_product_save_after>
  </events>
</adminhtml>
......
</config>
```

customerextras.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/pmx-css.css</stylesheet>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </default>
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
      <action method="addTab">
        <name>my_customerextras_tab</name>
        <block>customerextras/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

I need to show the same block in new product create page in admin, Is there any way for that from the above code like adding `adminhtml->layout->create` tags in the config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your should add `</adminhtml_catalog_product_new>` section to the customerextras.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/pmx-css.css</stylesheet>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </default>
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
      <action method="addTab">
        <name>my_customerextras_tab</name>
        <block>customerextras/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
      <action method="addTab">
        <name>my_customerextras_tab</name>
        <block>customerextras/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
      </action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```